# Can aborting a process without resetting the clipboard chain cause trouble?

Tags: windows, winapi, clipboard

I've got a program that calls [SetClipboardViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at startup to register for clipboard change notifications.  At shutdown time, it will call [ChangeClipboardChain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove itself from the chain correctly.

This is all great as long as the program runs normally. But that's got me wondering, what happens if the program gets aborted, either by me killing it under the debugger, by a crash, or by the user killing the process because something went wrong?  Then the cleanup never happens.  Can that cause trouble for the system somehow?

Specifically, I know Windows can remove my viewer without trouble because it's a handle and Windows can clean up all handles when a process terminates, but will this cause the next value downstream in the chain, that I was holding a reference to, to get lost somehow?

Comment: I don't see anything definitive (or this would be an answer rather than a comment), but a Google search indicates that failing to call `ChangeClipboardChain` or incorrectly handling the `WM_CHANGECBCHAIN` message is potentially disastrous.

Comment: @Jim: I must not be searching for the same terms as you; I don't see that.  Link please?

Comment: See the "community content" at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649052(VS.85).aspx. Also, see the documentation for `WM_CHANGECBCHAIN` and realize that if you don't call the `SendMessage` function to notify the window in line when things change, things can go bad very quickly. I searched for [setclipboardviewer error] and [changeclipboardchain] error, and read some of the comments. Nothing definitive, but indications that one should tread carefully.

Comment: It's very brittle, one mis-behaving app is enough to break it.  Favor AddClipboardFormatListener() available in Vista and up.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, failure to remove yourself from the chain will break the chain. Deadly sin #2.  Please read the whole list to be sure that you're following all of the rules.
http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows/6
Lots of apps suffer from this, including the Delphi IDE.  i.e. if Delphi crashes in certain ways, it'll kill the clipboard chain (D2005 anyway).

Consider using Vista style notification on Vista/Windows7.