# Winform application random crashes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed an application that catches all Clipboard text:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    try
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
            {
                if (Clipboard.GetText() != string.Empty)
                    //I analyze the data then 
                    if (ClipboardObject.CheckNewData(Clipboard.GetText()))
                        ClipboardObject.UpdateClipboardData(Clipboard.GetText());

                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                break;
            }
            case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                    nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                else
                    SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

When the event is risen, i fill the data in an object that is shared to my whole application then in timer that ticks every half second i keep checking if there is new data in this object.

On every pc i have installed this application on, strange things start happening to windows even when my application isn't running:

- Windows keeps crashing randomly
- On some pc's windows mini-freeze happens (happens with me every time)
- Sometime windows will crash as soon as i press mouse  right click on any folder or file

I have been struggling with these issues for a long time and i really can't find any solution to my problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any COM here?

Comment: *even when my application isn't running* sounds like you forgot to remove installed hook.

Comment: Can you tell me how remove the hook ? Does that mean everytime i run the application i attach a hook, so that means there are multiple hooks running or only one hook can be attached only ? Is there anyway to check if there is already a hook attached ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Each window that receives the `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` message must call the SendMessage function to pass the message on to the next window in the clipboard viewer chain." 
Are you sure that *always* happens? You should have a try ... finally block there (in fact, GetText probably throws if the data isn't textual).

The `WM_CHANGECBCHAIN` could also be very tricky - do you clean up after yourself on application exit? You have to remove yourself again using `ChangeClipboardChain`, otherwise you leave a dangling pointer in the clipboard chain!

Basically, when your form is closing (and it's handle is getting disposed - but before it really is disposed), you need to call something like this:

```
ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
```

The clipboard change is extremely brittle - a crashing application can leave you with broken clipboard. In .NET, at least try to use a finalizer to dispose of this (even then, it's going to be tricky) - in fact, it may not be a bad idea to bind the clipboard to something else rather than your actual window (so that you can implement the dispose-finalize pattern properly), but that's up to you. Also, see this question:
[Can aborting a process without resetting the clipboard chain cause trouble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709311/can-aborting-a-process-without-resetting-the-clipboard-chain-cause-trouble)

Note that even then, someone can just process kill your application (that's one of the reasons Task Manager warns you not to kill processes - in this case, it really *will* make your application unstable). Triple-check everything to make sure you dispose of the CB chain in every possible scenario (except for the unavoidable process kill - there are ways to fix even this in a way, but hey, if the user is being in ass, let him), otherwise you're going to leave your PC very unstable.

Comment: Your information is very helpful, i will try everything you noted and hopefully it will work